# Spark inner query resulting in large number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark

I have seen the following behavior in Apache spark a couple of times. Am unable to construe what constitutes such behavior?so reaching out to spark wide community.

Consider the following simple query

```
select emp_name,emp_id, emp_addr from employee where emp_dob in (select cal_dt from calendar where mon = 'oct' and year=1990)
```

Here we are just trying to fetch all employees with the birth month is 'Oct' in the year 1990. This query results in several few thousand partitions more compared to the one below

```
select emp_name,emp_id, emp_addr from employee where emp_dob in ('1990-10-01','1990-10-02','1990-10-03'....'1990-10-31')
```

Can someone help me to understand this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This has been handled in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11150 which is coming in Spark 3.0. Hope that helps.